# Lining up different sized divs through different zoom levels

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of what I am doing: http://jsfiddle.net/wFjXD/

At a certain zoom level ( the default on my machine ), the top 2 divs have the same width as the bottom 10.

This is because I set the width in pixels, each small div has a width of 20px and a 1px border. The larger divs have a width of 108 px which makes each long div line up with 5 of the small divs.

The problem is that if you zoom in or out using ctrl + or ctrl - in the browser, all of this changes and the divs will no longer line up.

Is there a css fix to maintain the same relative sizes through different zoom levels?
Or is there another best practice way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Zoom techniques vary from browser to browser. Attempting to make them all work the way you want at all zoom levels is nearly pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the *proportion* to stay the same, use `%` instead of `px`.
Thats the best I can think of for your problem. Although it'd have to be a fixed number of children and you'd have to wrap them appropriately.

To give you an [idea](http://jsfiddle.net/wFjXD/13/)...